# What does limit of a derivative imply?

Tags: derivatives

If the limit of a derivative of a function when x tending to infinity exists, it is zero. ( Considering limit of the function at x tending to infinity is finite.)

I wonder what this limit implies, physically or graphically.

Comment: The assertion is not true as written, the limit of the derivative need not exist. **If** it exists, then it is $0$.

Comment: I think one intuitive meaning could be that the function's graph "flattens down" towards the horizontal line $\;y=L\;$ ...and this line's derivative is zero, indeed.

Comment: @DonAntonio- Actually this is what my doubt was. Are we saying that the limit of derivative when x tending to infinity represents taking derivative once again? I wonder how could limit imply that.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks. I have edited my question. Hope it is correct now.

Comment: Not quite, the existence of the (finite) limit of the function itself is important. Otherwise look at $f(x) = x$, the limit of the derivative is $1$.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks once again. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel pointed out, your assertion is incorrect. If a function approaches some value L (presumably a horizontal asymptote) when $x$ goes to infinity, then the derivative does not have to go to zero at all. Under "high school" circumstances, it usually will (most of those functions behave kind of "nice"?), however, consider the following counter example: $y=\frac{sinx^2}{x}$. It is clear that for large $x$, the $y$ goes to zero. The derivative of this function is $y'=\frac{2x^2cosx^2-sinx^2}{x^2}$ which simplifies to $2cosx^2-\frac{sinx^2}{x^2}$. Is it clear that the derivative will never go to zero for larger $x$?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I have edited my question as pointed out by Daniel.

Comment: Your example has been very helpful though. Thanks.